# Saving more corsor positions (with tput?) in bash terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, cursor

I know that `tput sc` saves the current cursor position and `tput rc` restores it exactly where `tput sc` was called. The problem is that every time `tput sc` is called, it overwrites the previous saved position.

Is there a way to save more positions, e.g. `tput sc pos1` and `tput sc pos2` which can be restored with, say, `tput rc pos1` and `tput rc pos2` respectively? (The solution need not make use of `tput`, I mentioned it because it's the only command I know that handles cursor position)

If not, is there a way to at least save the cursor position *locally* in a function, so that if a function uses `tput sc` and then calls another function that runs again `tput sc`, then each function restores its own saved cursor position when invoking `tput rc`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following function to extract current cursor position in a simple array:

```bsh
extract_current_cursor_position () {
    export $1
    exec < /dev/tty
    oldstty=$(stty -g)
    stty raw -echo min 0
    echo -en "\033[6n" > /dev/tty
    IFS=';' read -r -d R -a pos
    stty $oldstty
    eval "$1[0]=$((${pos[0]:2} - 2))"
    eval "$1[1]=$((${pos[1]} - 1))"
}
```

<sup>(the source of code used in this function was taken and adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575525/2353900))</sup>

Now, for example, to save current cursor position in `pos1`, use:

```
extract_current_cursor_position pos1
```

To save current cursor position in `pos2`, use:

```
extract_current_cursor_position pos2
```

To see cursor positions saved in `pos1` and `pos2`, you can use:

```
echo ${pos1[0]} ${pos1[1]}
echo ${pos2[0]} ${pos2[1]}
```

To move/restore cursor position to `pos1`, you have to use:

```
tput cup ${pos1[0]} ${pos1[1]}
```

To move/restore cursor position to `pos2`, you have to use:

```
tput cup ${pos2[0]} ${pos2[1]}
```

Answer (score 6):

`tput` command works through terminal control sequences, listed here: http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~tapted/ansi.html There is a sequence for extracting current position (Query Cursor Position - `\e[6n`) and looks like it's not present in `tput`. To extract it use:

```
stty -echo; echo -n $'\e[6n'; read -d R x; stty echo; echo ${x#??}
30;1
```

Now you can extract row position saved in `$x` to some other variable and move your cursor using `tput cup` later:

```
$ echo $my_saved_pos
12
$ tput cup $my_saved_pos 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`tput` was mentioned with a `?`, so consider ANSI codes movement codes:

- `$'\e[s'` - Saves current position
- `$'\e[u'` - Restores previous position

Example:

```
$ printf "\e[s\e[6CWORLD\e[uHELLO\n"
HELLO WORLD
```